# ¿Cómo mostrar un formulario n cantidad de veces?

Tags: php, html

buen día. El día de hoy tengo una duda con la cual quiero que me ayuden por favor.Verán, tengo el siguiente formulario el cual solicita la cantidad de estudiantes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le presiono 2 estudiantes y esto es lo que me ejecuta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que en lugar de mostarme los dos formularios para ingresar las notas de los estudiantes en una misma pagina, me muestre un solo formularo para el estudiante 1 y cuando de en enviar me muestre el otro formulario correspondiente al estudiante 2. De antemano, muchas gracias por su ayuda.

---

Aqui el codigo de la primera imagen

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
 <title>Ciclos</title>
 </head>
 <body class="fondo">
     <div class="container">
     <h2 class="d-flex justify-content-center titulo text- white">Bienvenidos al Calculo de Notas</h2>                                              
       <?php
            echo '<form action="operac.php" method="post" class="form-group">';
                $cantAlumnos = $_POST["cantAlumnos"];//Esta es la variable que me trae la cantidad de alumnos
                    for ($i=1; $i <= $cantAlumnos; $i++) { 
                        echo '<label for="" class="text-white">Estudiante #'.$i.'</label><br>';

                        echo '<label for="" class="text-white">Nota 1:</label>';
                        echo '<input type="text" name="txtNotaUno" class="form-control" Required placeholder="Ingrese la Nota 1">';

                        echo '<label for="" class="text-white">Nota 2:</label>';
                        echo '<input type="text" name="txtNotadDos" class="form-control" Required placeholder="Ingrese la Nota 2">';

                        echo '<label for="" class="text-white">Nota 3:</label>';
                        echo '<input type="text" name="txtNotaTres" class="form-control" Required placeholder="Ingrese la Nota 3">';

                        echo '<label for="" class="text-white">Nota 4:</label>';

                        echo '<input type="text" name="txtNotaCuatro" class="form-control" Required placeholder="Ingrese la Nota 4">';
                        echo '<input type="Submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block">';
                        echo '<input type="Reset" value="Limpiar" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">';       
                    }
            echo '</form>'            
    ?>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Sin el código involucrado será difícil además que has intentado?

Comment: Que pena, ya agregué el código. Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: ¿Qué caso tiene preguntar la cantidad de alumnos? Puedes mostrar contínuamente el formulario, y el usuario decidirá cuándo dejar de enviarlo. Y si es necesario, puedes llevar el conteo por otro lado.